# SpringBeanFacesELResolver does not work with tomcat el

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2, tomcat8

I created a project with follwoing configuration:

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">



<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

UserQuery.java

```
@Component("userQuery")
@SpringViewScope
public class UserQuery implements Serializable
{
    private String test = "test";
    //getter, setter for test
}
```

test.xhtml

```
#{userQuery} // this works, returns userquery object
#{userQuery.test} //throw null pointer exception
```

exception :

```
    SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml: null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:207)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Introspector.isAssignable(Introspector.java:809)
```

PS : when I remove SpringBeanFacesELResolver and use jsf @ManagedBean instead of @component #{userQuery.test} also works but I don't want to use this way.

what is wrong with spring ?

I'm using tomcat 8.5.16

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade JDK 1.8_5 to 1.8.77 and the problem is solved.